# How can I flip groups of columns horizontally in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a table as such:

```
X Y Z
1 4 9
2 7 2
3 4 8
3 4 9
...
```

I would like to produce the following table:

```
1 4 9 2 7 2 3 4 8 3 4 9
```

Even better would be:

```
X Y Z X Y Z X Y Z X Y Z
1 4 9 2 7 2 3 4 8 3 4 9
```

Comment: You can only convert as range, for table the name is unique.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Please take the [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to get your first badge

Answer (score 1):

With *X* in A1, you can grab the CurrentRegion (data island) that extends out into an array. The rest is just loops and a little math.

```
Option Explicit

Sub buildXYZ()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, arr1 As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet4")

        'collect source values
        arr1 = .Cells(1, "A").CurrentRegion.Value

        'create the target array
        ReDim arr2(1 To 2, 1 To (UBound(arr1, 1) - 1) * UBound(arr1, 2))

        'populate target from source using two loops
        For i = LBound(arr1, 1) + 1 To UBound(arr1, 1)
            For j = LBound(arr1, 2) To UBound(arr1, 2)
                arr2(1, j + (i - 2) * UBound(arr1, 2)) = arr1(1, j)
                arr2(2, j + (i - 2) * UBound(arr1, 2)) = arr1(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i

        'put target values back into worksheet
        .Cells(1, "E").Resize(UBound(arr2, 1), UBound(arr2, 2)) = arr2

    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

If you need to perform the operation 'in place' then work with the worksheet cells directly and avoid transition arrays.

```
Option Explicit

Sub buildXYZ2()

    Dim i As Long, lr As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet4")

        'collect last data row
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'loop through the rows backwards, shifting the values up and right
        For i = lr To 3 Step -1
            With .Range(.Cells(i, "A"), .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
                .Parent.Cells(i - 1, .Parent.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, .Columns.Count) = .Value
                .Clear
            End With
        Next i

        'AutoFill the headers across in a pattern
        With .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
            .AutoFill Destination:=.Resize(1, .Columns.Count * (lr - 1)), Type:=xlFillCopy
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with formulas.

[image]

For the column headings, the formula in E1 is:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,0,MOD(COLUMN()-2,3))
```

Copy it across as needed.  `COLUMN()-2` adjusts for the starting column of the output.  You want the first output column to be adjusted to a value of 3 (mine starts in column 5), so that the MOD function returns `0` offset relative to the first data column.  If your data doesn't start in A1, you will need to adjust for that.

The output values row uses the same formula but replaces the `0` row offset to increment data rows.  The formula in E2:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,CEILING((COLUMN()-4)/3),MOD(COLUMN()-2,3))
```

For the row increment, `COLUMN()-4` adjusts the column so that the first result location is `1` (mine starts in column 5).  Again, adjust the formula if the source data doesn't start in A1.

I kept this simple.  Just copy across as needed.  When you pass the end of the source data, the results will start displaying zeros for blank source cells.